# Does shopping for car insurance affect credit ratings?

Tags: insurance

Out of curiosity, does shopping for car insurance play a role in credit ratings?

For example, do they pull your credit when creating a quote? The reason I ask is I know when I left my parents' insurance plan their rates changed due to my credit rating no longer being factored in.

Comment: That will probably depend on your state/country.  Some regions prohibit use of credit data for auto insurance underwriting.

Comment: Are you sure your parents' rate changed because of your credit rating and not the fact that there was one less person/car to insure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In most states in the United States, for many insurers, [yes, your credit report is one factor in determining your rate](https://www.esurance.com/info/car/myth-your-credit-score-doesnt-affect-your-insurance-rate).  California, Massachusetts, and Hawaii are the (current) exceptions to that; in those states it's not legal to do so.

The credit check is a [soft pull](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/insurance-inquires-do-not-affect-credit-scores/), though, and does not affect your credit score.  So the answer to your primary question is **no**, it does not affect your credit score, but it is affected *by* your credit score (or more accurately your credit report; the score used is a custom score, not the standard FICO score.)

Your parents' rates may have decreased due to many factors, including your presence in general (particularly if you're under 25), but one of those factors could be your credit history - though it's not necessarily the case that your credit factored into the rate at all. You could ask the insurer if it is factored in, or if only the primary insured's credit is pulled.